# How to merge 3 arrays keeping their meta key?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm Getting some arrays from some wordpress custom fields:

```
$content = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'content'));
$media = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'media'));
$yt = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'youtube'));
```

I then need to have it printing in sequence, like:

> media
>
> content
>
> LInk
>
> Embed

And repeat the sequence for each value

```
media

content

LInk

Embed
```

For the sequence I'd use this:

```
echo '<ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_array['media']); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($all_array['content']); $j++) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($all_array['youtube']); $k++) {
            echo '<li>media->' . $all_array['media'][$i] . '</li>';
            echo '<li>content->' . $all_array['content'][$j] . '</li>';
            echo '<li>link->' . $all_array['link'][$k] . '</li>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

But I'm doing something wrong with the merging of the 3 fields as if I do a `var_dump` before to run the `for` bit, like

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($all_array, true) . '</pre>';
```

Then this is what I get and I cannot iterate as I wish:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => '
brother

',
      1 => '
Lorem

',
      2 => '
End it

',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => '337',
      1 => '339',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94q6fzbJUfg',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Literally the layout in html that I'm looking for is:

1. image
2. content
3. link
4. image
5. content
6. link
   ...

**UPDATE**

This how I am merging the arrays:

```
foreach ( $content as $idx => $val ) {
  $all_array[] = [ $val, $media[$idx], $yt[$idx] ];
}
```

This is the associative array how it looks like:

Content:

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => '
    brother
    
    ',
        1 => '
    Lorem
    
    ',
        2 => '
    End it
    
    ',
      ),
    )
```

Media

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => '337',
        1 => '339',
      ),
    )
```

Youtube

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94q6fzbJUfg',
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Please include an example of the source arrays with associative context and the code that is building the `$all_array` currently. There would need to be something to associate the records to one another in each of the arrays, otherwise you may need to use a custom [`wp_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to include the associations.

Comment: I meant a bit more of the data from the 3 source arrays of `$content`, `$media`, and `$yt`, so that we can produce an example of your dataset in our answers.

Comment: @WillB. I have updated with each single var_dump now, please bear in mind they're dynamic so the actual values for each meta might be more or less

Comment: Please show the exact desired result produced from the data you provided. The phrasing of your description is inconsistent and hard to follow.

Comment: Where is the associative array? You only build/show  auto-indexed multidimensional arrays

Comment: I don't see a clear [mcve] here.  It is is too much of a rambling scattering of information for me to follow.

Comment: @ArleighHix where is the inconsistency of my phrasing? Also I did provide the desidered output.

Comment: @rob.m given the array example provided, this snippet should accomplish your desired output: https://3v4l.org/59Hs7 if it does not work, please provide an updated array example. The process iterates over all of the associations incrementally until no more are found or the maximum number of all Iterable elements has been completed.

Comment: However, the current structure of the arrays appears to break the associations between each of the values, since the index of each media, content, and link is incremental rather than associative.  Meaning the `link` (`$yt[0][0]`) may actually be associated with the last `content` (`$content[0][2]`) entry rather than the first (`$content[0][0]`). An optimal array structure to maintain associations should follow `$entries = [['content1','media1','link1'], ['content2','media2','link2']]`.

Comment: @WillB. I've resolved it but they've closed my question and I cannot play my own answer :(

Comment: @WillB. basically I've resolved like this https://pastebin.com/xjUXLRNE

Comment: @rob.m Yes, I see that in your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74366870/1144627). Please be sure to read the [*How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) to prevent posting several related questions as you're working through debugging a problem and avoid closures or other repercussions.

Comment: @WillB. thanks a know It works here, but the two questions have totally different code and issue. While yes I was debugging, I also totally changed the code and approach hence the questions. Anyway, result is positive. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I've resolved it is first I calculate the tot. items within each array, then I get the array with max items and loop and add the items in sequence:

```
//GET CUSTOM FIELDS
    $content = get_post_meta($post_to_edit->ID, 'content', false);
    $media = get_post_meta($post_to_edit->ID, 'media', false);
    $yt = get_post_meta($post_to_edit->ID, 'youtube', false);
    $max = max(count($content), count($media), count($yt));
    $combined = [];
//
// CREATE CUSTOM FIELDS UNIQUE ARRAY
for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    if(isset($media[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "media", "value" => $media[$i]];
    }
    if(isset($content[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "content", "value" => $content[$i]];
    }
    if(isset($yt[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "youtube", "value" => $yt[$i]];
    } 
}
```

Finally I can loop:

```
foreach ($combined as $key => $val) {
   if($val['type'] === "media") {
     ...
   }
   if($val['type'] === "content") {
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to merge the arrays together. It will work fine in separate arrays. However, your `for` loops don't have the right logic. Try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($media); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($media[$i]); $j++) {
        echo '<li>media->' . $media[$i][$j] . '</li>';
    }
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($content[$i]); $j++) {
        echo '<li>content->' . $content[$i][$j] . '</li>';
    }
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($youtube[$i]); $j++) {
        echo '<li>link->' . $youtube[$i][$j] . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `count()` on every iteration if the count never changes?  Any reason that you are not using a `foreach()`?

Comment: I used count as I was assuming that $media[$i], $content[$i] and $youtube[$i] could have different lengths based on $i. But `foreach` would work just as well.

Comment: @leighboz that's not working, first of all we get the first letter only of the value and secondly we don't get media>content>link but we repeat them `media->3
media->3
content-><
content->p
content->>
link->h`